# ElasticSearch Aggregation with Group By on Nested Property

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, aggregate

I am trying to develop an ElasticSearch aggregation query that performs binning of results based upon a property in a nested object.

```
product :
{
    productName : String,
    manufacturerInfo : {
        manufacturerName : String
    }
}
```

The corresponding mappings are setup for the index.

The query that I need should look like this:

```
{
    "size" : 0,
    "aggs" : {
        "manufacturers" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "manufacturerInfo.manufacturerName.keyword"
            }
        },
        "aggs" : {
            "productNames" : {
                "terms" : {
                    "field" : "productName.keyword"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The query needs to group by the name of the nested property but bin properties from the root object and this seems to cause some trouble in ElasticSearch.

When the following is attempted to precatenate:

```
"aggs" : {
    "root" : {
        "nested" : {
            "path" : "manufacturerInfo"
         }
     },
     ...
 }
```

it does not appear that this context allows binning of items based upon the root of the product object.

What is the correct syntax to bin the productNames corresponding to the manufacturerNames specified in the nested manufacturerInfo objects?

Answer (score 0):

The nested context:

```
"aggs" : {
    "root" : {
        "nested" : {
            "path" : "manufacturerInfo"
         }
     },
```

must be used in conjunction with the reverse_nested {} - nested aggs syntax that is inserted prior to reference to the parent object's property that is binned:

```
    "aggs" : {
        "products" : {
            "reverse_nested" : {}, "aggs" : { "productNames" : { 
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "productName.keyword"
            } } }
        }
    }
```